# Google Sheets show only one unique row using Query

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I have a combined tab which pulls in loads of sheets to provide a master sheet but I'm trying to work out a way to show only one occurrence when a  duplicate occurs

My thinking is that I need to use query as I need to only set some criteria

Column D contains a unique key for each row but this row will appear in other sheets slightly different with only Cell D being the same value

```
=UNIQUE(QUERY(Combined!A2:Z,"select * where D matches '"&TEXTJOIN("|",1,Combined!D2:D)&"'" and (E='Cross' or E='Con') ,0))
```

I thought I could use matches and unique as above to achieve this but sadly I'm not getting anywhere

Any guidance would be great

Sheet - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1P29rAgAkTN4_0XZ5BZ6mYni_foOYzgxey3rp5Jor3mI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: sorry, updated now

Comment: Only show one occurrence of a duplicate in the combined sheet - If I can do this using query, it will allow me to having other matching criteria as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wrap it all in **`QUERY`** and query it out further as you want:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(UNIQUE(QUERY(IF(COUNTIF(Combined!D:D, Combined!D:D)>1, 
 {Combined!D:D, Combined!A:C}, ), "select Col1 where Col1 is not null")),
 QUERY(IF(COUNTIF(Combined!D:D, Combined!D:D)>1, {Combined!D:D, Combined!A:C}, ), 
 "where Col1 is not null"), {2,3,4,1}, 0)))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thanks, this looks like an awesome query - let me test it out - {2,3,4,1} what does this refer to in the vlookup?

Comment: {2,3,4,1} - order of columns to get from vlookup

Comment: So if I need to extend the columns being pulled across from Combined to A:Z , do I need to update the order of the columns as well?

Comment: yeah, you will need to